# Pandas read excel with openpyxl numbers change to strings

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have an excel file and I am reading it with `pandas.read_excel()` via:

```
df = pd.read_excel('excel_file.xlsx')
```

I would like to get the value of the column `'ATC'`, the problem is eventhough the column is a number (340.0) in excel sheet, `read_excel()` changes it to a funny string (see below):

```
>>>df['ATC']
0    _x0033_40.00
Name: ATC, dtype: object

>>>df['ATC'][0]
'_x0033_40.00'
```

**How can I fix this?**

Here is the excel file:
https://easyupload.io/amkucd

**EDIT:**

- I am already using `openpyxl` because new version of `xlrd` does not support `.xlsx` files.
- Setting engine as `engine='openpyxl'` does not do anything
- Tried to change the `dtype` of the ATC column as float. `ValueError: Unable to convert column ATC to type float`
- Cannot convert the `df['ATC']` to float via `.astype(float)` afterwards gives an could not convert string to float error.
- `pandas 1.2.3` and `openpyxl 3.0.7`

Comment: I don't know why pandas reading it like this i.e it converts value of column **ATC** `340.00` to `_x0033_40.00` and it's same mostly with all other columns

Comment: I also have the same problem